# Row was updated or deleted by another transaction error in login event listener?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have a simple spring security login event listener registered as

```
class LoginEventListener implements
    ApplicationListener<InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent> {

    //deal with successful login
    void onApplicationEvent(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
        User.withTransaction {

            def user = User.get(event.authentication.principal.id)
            user.lastLoginTime = new Date() // update login time
            user.save()

        }


    }


}
```

In the logs for every few login attempt the error i am getting is

```
ERROR 2017-06-13 16:24:04,090 [ajp-bio-8109-exec-4561] events.PatchedDefaultFlushEventListener: Could not synchronize database state with session
org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [User#2876]
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:686)
    at com.runnercard.LoginEventListener.onApplicationEvent(LoginEventListener.groovy:12)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I want to know how can i avoid this error? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use lock

```
def user = User.get(event.authentication.principal.id ,[lock: true])
```